# Scaffolding User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

im kinda new on Asp.net mvc and in my project i will have a user registration, a edit user profile and the possibility to view an user profile (create,edit,details), is there a way that i can add new propertys to the user table so i can scaffold the user? at the moment i just did this:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Telemóvel { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public string Sobre { get; set; }


}
```

Do i need to extend the user identity to do what i want??? how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Scaffolding are usually done through **ViewModels** not on **Model** classes. To achieve this, make your Identity User with (custom properties if necessary), add a migration and create a separate ViewModel class with custom properties required to register a new user and map the against Identity user in the post action.